# How to rearrange select result using condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am new to linq I am looking for solution for following table. 
Here is my table structure
[image]

By using `TransType` as condition I want to create two new columns `Credit` and `Debit` and want to show data according `TransType` condition.

like following screenshot.
[image]

Can you please suggest me LINQ select query to get result according to 2 screenshot.
Thank You.

Comment: Try `Where` Method: `var credits = transactions.Where(t=>t.TransType == "Credit");`

Comment: Your question is too broad, as there are many different ways to approach the problem, and which to use depends on information you haven't provided (including a good [mcve]). But, you can use `Select()` to project to a new element type, one that includes the `Credit` and `Debit` properties, setting the value according to the `TransType` column. So I'd suggest you try that. (I'll note that in many accounting contexts, there is no `TransType` column...credit/debit is indicated simply by the sign of the value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions.

```
from o in erp.CompAccTransactions
                                  where o.CompanyId == cid
                                  select new
                                     {
                                         o.TransId,
                                         o.TransDate,
                                         o.TransType,
                                         o.TransDesc,
                                         o.PaymentRef,
                                         Credit = o.TransType == "Credit" ? o.Amount : (o.TransType == "Debit" ? (decimal?)null : (decimal?)null),
                                         Debit = o.TransType == "Debit" ? o.Amount : (o.TransType == "Credit" ? (decimal?)null : (decimal?)null),
                                         o.ClearBalance

                                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get two extra columns, you could create your own custom class or generate anonymous class on the fly (you can always pass it anywhere through `dynamic` data type). The code shows the principle. In this case, I use anonymous class, so I have to repeat all fields in original object plus add two extra columns:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<MyObj>
    {
        new MyObj { TransType = "Credit", PaymentMethod = 1, Amount = 1000 },
        new MyObj { TransType = "Debit", PaymentMethod = 2, Amount = 2000 },
        new MyObj { TransType = "Debit", PaymentMethod = 1, Amount = 4000 },
        new MyObj { TransType = "Credit", PaymentMethod = 3, Amount = 3000 }
    };

    var filtered = from o in list
                   where o.TransType == "Credit"
                   select new
                   {
                      o.TransType,
                      o.PaymentMethod,
                      o.Amount,
                      Credit = "<VALUE>",
                      Debit = "<VALUE>"
                   };
}
class MyObj
{
    public string TransType { get; set; }
    public int PaymentMethod { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```